# Multimple WHERE conditions for different results in one SQL query

Tags: sql, count

I have a big problem with combining 3 SQL queries into one simple query that returns me all I want. Is tehere any way to join these simple sql queries into one?

query1:

```
SELECT COUNT(FieldID) AS "CountA"
FROM table WHERE Rezervovany = 0 AND Prodany = 0
```

query2:

```
SELECT COUNT(FieldID) AS "CountB"
FROM table WHERE Rezervovany = 1 AND Prodany = 0
```

query3:

```
SELECT COUNT(FieldID) AS "CountC"
FROM table WHERE Prodany = 1
```

Comment: Please precise what's your DBMS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put your conditions in a `case` clause inside the aggregate `count` function:

```
SELECT Count(CASE 
               WHEN rezervovany = 0 AND prodany = 0 THEN fieldid 
               ELSE NULL 
             END) AS "CountA", 
       Count(CASE 
               WHEN rezervovany = 1 AND prodany = 0 THEN fieldid 
               ELSE NULL 
             END) AS "CountB", 
       Count(CASE 
               WHEN prodany = 1 THEN fieldid 
               ELSE NULL 
             END) AS "CountC" 
FROM   table
```

Keep in mind that `count` only counts non-null values.

Comment: if this is for SQL Server, I think you are missing your `CASE` keywords

Comment: @paul The rush made me forget `case`. That's fixed now, it will work on other rdbms as well now

Comment: Thank you, that is working exactly as I needed! Looks really simple, I didn't know that CASE can be used like this.

Comment: @JacobH Great. And also, welcome to StackOverflow. Don't forget to upvote correct answers and to accept the answer that helped you the most

Comment: I believe there is an alternative of using union. At least it works in MS SQL.

Comment: @LajosArpad This solution does not use union and is ANSI SQL compatible. I'm not sure I understood you comment, could you elaborate?

Comment: I like your solution, don't get me wrong (that's why I upvoted your answer). I've just pointed out that union can also be used.

Comment: @LajosArpad I get it now. There's an answer here that uses union, but I think is partially complete, because OP wants 3 columns and one row, the answer returns one column and three rows

Comment: Exactly, however, in general it's better to use the select-case solution because it's quicker, but if there are many cases and sub-cases it might be an option to use the union idea instead for code clarity, but that case is the exception from the rule. I recommend your solution to anyone unless there is a valid argument against it in a certain situation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the rows one after the other, you can do this :

```
SELECT COUNT(FieldID) AS "CountA" FROM table WHERE Rezervovany = 0 AND Prodany = 0
union
SELECT COUNT(FieldID) AS "CountB" FROM table WHERE Rezervovany = 1 AND Prodany = 0
union
SELECT COUNT(FieldID) AS "CountC" FROM table WHERE Prodany = 1
```

[Reference (for MySQL)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)